# In unit testing how to cover all branches

Tags: java, junit, eclemma

I am writing junit test cases and using ECLEMMA for checking unit test coverage.
I have following code in ServerClass.class
This class is setting the status of a server.

```
         public class ServerClass{
         private boolean isStarted;
         public static final String MESSAGE_START = "Started";

         private void setStarted( boolean isStarted ) {
            this.isStarted = isStarted;
           }
         public String start() {
             setStarted( true );
             return ServerClass.MESSAGE_START;
           }
       }
```

I have a test case in my test class:

```
    @Test
     public void startTest(){
        ServerClass serverClass = new serverClass ();       
        assert("Started".equals( serverClass. start() )); // 3 of 4 branches missed
}
```

In eclipse, after running eclemma, I am getting a yellow dot in assert statement and code coverage is low.
Please help me in understanding the coverage logic and solution.

Comment: Post **real** code, and a screenshot of what you get.

Answer (score 3):

The JUnit method to check that something is true is named `assertTrue()`, not `assert()`. `assert()` is a native Java assertion, that won't be executed if assertions are not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a test for setStarted:

```
@Test
public void setStarted(){
    ServerClass serverClass = new serverClass ();       
    serverClass.setStarted(false);
    //assert a getter for isStarted (not in your example)
    assert (serverClass.isStarted() == false);
}
```

Comment: setStarted is private.

Comment: You can make it protected and I think that JUnit can access it. Besides, can you show what branches are missed ?